# Apache 2.4 not compressing my files

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, debian, compression, apache2.4

I recently migrated to apache 2.4 from 2.2. Everything seems to work fine except my file compression. The application connects to another service API to get data. Running the application from the old server i can see that the data retrieved is being compressed because the size is few kb but on the new apache 2.4 one of the file size is about 6mb and the other never gets to load. It always fails.
Here is my htaccess configuration for the [apache 2.2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3FdSDYHAnlcUGVKRDg0cWt2azQ/view?usp=sharing) and [apache 2.4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3FdSDYHAnlcYmNVU29Vb25zaE0/view?usp=sharing).
From my understanding with the changes i have done it should have worked. I have enabled all the 3 modules needed for this.

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so 
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so 
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
```

I also enabled logging compression and here are the logs that I am getting

```
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2734/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2732/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2734/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2736/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2734/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2734/16165 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2735/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2734/16170 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2737/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2734/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2735/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2735/16170 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2736/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"POST /accountservices/getLogs/?sid=mpev115fs31ee6pdcg2mkdpts4 HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2736/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /pools/ HTTP/1.1" 2736/16175 (16%)
"GET /css/bs_addon.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/bs_datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /css/cake.bootstrap3.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
```

I need help in figuring out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve the issue. It had to do more with networking than apache related